# Find highest value in struct and output name

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct

I have a structure below and wish to print the name of the largest owner of each of cats, dogs, and rabbits. How would i go about finding the largest of the 3 and printing the largest owner of each? I have 300 populated owners with the 3 animals associated with them.

```
struct Animals
{
    string ownername;
    int cats;
    int dogs;
    int rabbits;
};
struct World
{
    Animals number[MAXANIMALS];
} myAnimalWorld;
```

Comment: how bout linear search?

Comment: Just iterate through the array and find the maximum values and idices?

Comment: for-loop, if-condition, = and ==, variables ... btw., why do you count animals with `double`?

Comment: Please show some code, or at least some pseudo-code of what you have tried.

Comment: Apologies, i have fixed it. You are right

Answer (score 1):

This seems really trivial.  Loop over the array once, keeping track of the max rabbit, max cat, and max dog count and owner.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and used something like this to get it.

```
int max = a[0];

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{

    if(max < a[i]) {
        max = a[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::max_element` with a custom comparator for each of the requirements.

Curiosity - why are the types `double`? Do you expect anyone to have 2.5 cats?